# Unable to add Firebase Invites SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to add the firebase invites sdk for iOS but am coming     across the errors below when trying to build. I have added each framework to my project as well as the resource files. My other firebase frameworks work fine.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_kABPersonFirstNameProperty", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABAddressBookGetPersonCount", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_kABPersonEmailProperty", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_kABPersonPhoneProperty", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABMultiValueGetCount", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions", referenced from:
      +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:] in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_kABPersonLastNameProperty", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABPersonHasImageData", referenced from:
      ___82+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:]_block_invoke in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
  "_ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion", referenced from:
      +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsCoalesced:mustHaveEmail:mustHavePhone:handler:] in FirebaseInvites(GPPAddressBook_57390648818180ba012ed5ff31bf3e09.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My project navigator, with the frameworks 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HA8g.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you using a dependency manager? if not, I would suggest Cocoapods to help you import and keep track of 3rd party libraries

Comment: Pierre, I'm using Carthage. Unfortunately, Firebase does not have official Carthage support yet. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and click the '+' to add AddressBook.framework.

[image]

Comment: That did it. Thank you!